# Special characters Å Ö Ä showing � character using UTF-8 encoding during JSON paring Android

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8

I am not getting any clue why Special characters Å Ö Ä showing � character using UTF-8 encoding during JSON paring Android. The following is the code i am using.

```
    myjson.put("name", "ÅsdfÖ")); 
    entity = new StringEntity(myjson.toString()); 

    entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json; charset=utf-8"));
    HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(URL);
    httppost.setHeader("content-Type", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("accept", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "token");
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

The response i am getting like  "name": "�sdf� and also showing the same in backend webpage.

I am not getting where is the problem though i am sending it using UTF-8 endconding ?

Comment: you're overriding the conten type with your `setHeader() app/json` call. There's no utf8 charset definition there.

Comment: check the database encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        JSONObject myjson= new JSONObject();
        myjson.put("name", "ÅsdfÖ"));

        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(myjson.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Mark answer as right if it works for you.